# Any way to exclude AdSupport class from Xamarin.iOS.dll

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, linker, idfa

Is there a way to exclude AdSupport class from Xamarin.ios.dll as I don't want Firebase Analytics SDK to use it?

I saw a way to exclude assemblies in Xamarin.ios Linker, but is it possible to exclude this AdSupport class of an assembly in Linker?

**Why I want to do this?** If the AdSupport is included in the app, Firebase says it will pick it up to access the IDFA. This is for the new privacy requirements in iOS 14 from Apple